# Accessing Listview index above index 9 in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a Listview control that displays data which has 12 columns. From column 1 to 9 it displays, but above 9 it doesn't displays the data even the index number is provided.

[image]
Check out bellow code which has indexes to display for all columns. Also See the above pic:

```
public void populateProductList()
{
    string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT";

    StockDbConnection dbcon = new StockDbConnection();
    SqlCeConnection Conn = new SqlCeConnection(dbcon.ReturnConnection("ConnString"));
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmdString, Conn);
    try
    {
        Conn.Open();

        SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        lstvwProduct.Items.Clear();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem obj=new ListViewItem();    
            obj.SubItems[0].Text = dr[0].ToString(); 
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[3].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[4].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[5].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[6].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[7].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[8].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[9].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[10].ToString());
            obj.SubItems.Add(dr[11].ToString());

            //in object of ListViewItem give display member at first and give value member at second position 
            lstvwProduct.Items.Add(obj);

            // add object to the listbox
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem is: index 10 and 11 doesn't display, I already have the column collection for them.

Comment: Did you tried debugging the lstvwProduct after adding the obj?

Comment: I second what @Joseph says, try debugging, stepping through the lines and see if index 9 - 11 even have a value. Maybe you could even try some direct commands, such as the size/count/length of `dr`.

Comment: Yes I have tried several time. The problem is not displaying the last two columns.

Comment: @Melvin Yes I treid that the dr[10] and dr[11] has a data, i checked it by diplaying using messageBox.show(dr[10].toString()), I think the problem is with listview index.

Comment: Do dr[10] and dr[11] if placed below dr[1] work??

Comment: Why do you treat [0] differently? Shouldn't you Add() it as well as the others?

Comment: I have also treated as dr[0], not work

Comment: Why you cannot use `DataGridView` control, this control of winforms is perfect solution for your purpose.

Comment: Ok thanks @Fabio I will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just try it by assigning a dataset to Gridview's datasource property.
it will be more helpful to you.

```
        public void populateProductList()
        {
            string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT";

            StockDbConnection dbcon = new StockDbConnection();
            SqlCeConnection Conn = new SqlCeConnection(dbcon.ReturnConnection("ConnString"));
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmdString, Conn);
            DataSet ds;
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();

                SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmdString, Conn);
                da.fill(ds);
                lstDGView.DataSource=ds;

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: DataSource is not active for Listview why?

Comment: @NurSelam Can you try with Datagrid view ?